# Glassfish 4.1 glassfish tools Eclipse Luna deploy error

Tags: eclipse-luna, glassfish-4.1

I recently upgraded, i.e. made a fresh install of Eclipse Luna and Glassfish 4.1. Both Apps are up-to-date.
Deploying a Java EE application is failing via Eclipse, if I do a standard-deploy via Glassfish-admin-console it works.
The error log is:

```
GlassFish: Error getting URL for WebResource[module=Module[TachionServer,org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TachionServer], path=]
```

Stack-Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException    
at java.net.Parts.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.AbstractGlassfishServer.getModuleRootURL(AbstractGlassfishServer.java:883)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.GlassfishLaunchableAdapterDelegate.getLaunchable(GlassfishLaunchableAdapterDelegate.java:55)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.LaunchableAdapter.getLaunchable(LaunchableAdapter.java:76)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.ServerUIPlugin.getLaunchableAdapter(ServerUIPlugin.java:1209)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.fragment.OptionalClientWizardFragment.updateClients(OptionalClientWizardFragment.java:65)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.fragment.OptionalClientWizardFragment.getChildFragments(OptionalClientWizardFragment.java:113)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.TaskWizard.addSubWizardFragments(TaskWizard.java:329)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.TaskWizard.addSubWizardFragments(TaskWizard.java:333)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.TaskWizard.getAllWizardFragments(TaskWizard.java:317)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.TaskWizard.performFinish(TaskWizard.java:167)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.actions.RunOnServerActionDelegate.run(RunOnServerActionDelegate.java:335)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.actions.RunOnServerActionDelegate.run(RunOnServerActionDelegate.java:764)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.ServerLaunchShortcut.launch(ServerLaunchShortcut.java:41)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found the solution: 
In the newest GlassFish-Tools for Eclipse the newest version, it seems to be necessary to create a WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server   3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>/hello2</context-root>
```